# REST Service not showing results in browser

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, rest, web-config

I am trying to create my own web service using Rest for a university Project. 
After doing some tutorials I have been able to create my own and the service is working and returning results in visual studio using the wcf test client.

When I browse to the service however (`http://localhost:53215/UserService1.svc`) I can see the service page but `http://localhost:53215/UserService1.svc/GetUsersNames` send gives me 404, page not found error!

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code.

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>    
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfRestSample.IUserService1">
        <endpoint address="" contract="WcfRestSample.IUserService1" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="cs4_databaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/cs4_model.csdl|res://*/cs4_model.ssdl|res://*/cs4_model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\cs4_database.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

IUserService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfRestSample
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IUserService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IUserService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        List<string> GetUsersNames();
    }
}
```

UserService1.svc

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfRestSample
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "UserService1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select UserService1.svc or UserService1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class UserService1 : IUserService1
    {
        public List<string> GetUsersNames()
        {
            using (cs4_databaseEntities entities = new cs4_databaseEntities())
            {
                return entities.Users.Select(user => user.Name).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The tutorials I used worked fine with the browser!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your endpoint is
`http://localhost:53215/UserService1.svc/rest/GetUsersNames`. The "rest" part comes from your configuration 'address="rest"'

**Editor:**

The service name is set to the interface not the implementation class, change:

```
<service name="WcfRestSample.IUserService1">
```

to

```
<service name="WcfRestSample.UserService1">
```

One consequence of this is the service no longer loads in the wcf test client, *maybe this is why its a source of confusion - some people document their steps to work with the wcf test client and others for a web browser* but its an easy fix to change it back to using the interface!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried this but still no luck! I've changed the address to ""

Comment: Try adding a UriTemplate to the operation's WebGet attribute. UriTemplate="GetUsersNames"

Comment: Still no luck! I added the uri template but no change!

Comment: is "<service name="WcfRestSample.IUserService1">" correct? i think it needs to be "<service name="WcfRestSample.UserService1">". So the implementation class, not the interface.

Answer (score 1):

changed `<service name="WcfRestSample.IUserService1">` to `<service name="WcfRestSample.UserService1">` . Thanks to User -Marvin Smitt in the comments

Comment: One consequence of this is that the service no longer comes up in the wcf test client, but its an easy fix to change it back to using the interface!